# Java while loop won't break (I've set my condition to false, too)

Tags: java, while-loop, infinite-loop

I've made something that rolls five dice until it gets a five-of-a-kind. I will paste my code below so you can see it. I HAVE set my while condition to false if the five-of-a-kind is successful. Nothing happens after it says "Rolling...". Should I be using .equals()?

```
package omega;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class One {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Random random = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int one = 1+random.nextInt(6);
        int two = 1+random.nextInt(6);
        int three = 1+random.nextInt(6);
        int four = 1+random.nextInt(6);
        int five = 1+random.nextInt(6);

        boolean rolling = true;
        int rollCount = 0;

        System.out.println("====================");
        System.out.println("      Yahtzee!      ");
        System.out.println("====================");
        System.out.println("");


            System.out.println("Type 0 to roll.");
            int roll = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Rolling...");

            while(rolling == true) {
                switch(roll) {
                case 0 :
                    if(two == one && three == one && four == one) {
                        rollCount++;
                        rolling = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        rollCount++;
                    }
                    break;
                default :
                    System.out.println("Invalid roll!");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Yahtzee!");
            System.out.println("Took " + rollCount + " rolls!");



    }


}
```

Comment: Where do you roll for a second time?

Comment: `while(rolling == true) {` is the same as `while (rolling)`. Never explicitly compare a boolean to true (or false), it's more verbose, and far too easy to write `while (rolling = true)`.

Comment: "_set my while condition to false if the five-of-a-kind is successful_" The condition in your code looks like it only checks for 4 of a kind. It checks if one == two, one == three, and one == four. Also, one, two, three, four, and five never get changed throughout your whole program - they are the same the whole time.

Comment: And separately, I thought all five dice had to be equal to get a Yahtzee!  Your code will give me a Yahtzee! when the first four match.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `roll` variable? It isn't used (meaningfully anyway). What was the intention? IS it supposed to be max rolls or something?

Comment: Congrats on getting this far as an 11-year-old.  Before you do anything else you MUST learn how to use the debugger in your IDE.  It allows you to step through your code one line at a time and examine the values of variables as you go.  Had you used the debugger you would have easily found the errors in your code, and learned far more than by asking here.  Use the debugger first and ask here when you run into something you can't explain to yourself after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `rolling` to false if `roll` is not 0.

```
default :
    System.out.println("Invalid roll!");
    rolling = false;
```

Thus when your `while` loop re-runs, it will notice the `false` condition and break.

Answer (score 5):

You're not rerolling inside the loop. If `roll` isn't 0, it'll be an infinite loop, printing "Invalid roll!" over and over and over.

Answer (score 0):

There is few things that can lead to infinite loop here

1. First one is your `roll` variable always **zero** you are not
   rolling again or not changing that variable.
2. Second one is there is less possibility that the **one** to **five** variables
   going through the `if` condition.

`if(two == one && three == one && four == one) {
    rollCount++;
    rolling = false;
}`

*Also you do not need to use `while(rolling == true)` instead you can use `while(rolling)` because your rolling variable initialized as true*.

Here is what I came up with

```
            while(rolling) {
                switch(roll) {
                case 0 :
                    if(two == one && three == one && four == one) {
                        rollCount++;
                        rolling = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        rollCount++;
                        System.out.println("If you want to stop roll press -1: ");
                        System.out.println("Or type 0 to roll again.");
                        roll = scan.nextInt();

                        if(roll == -1){
                            System.out.println("Yahtzee!");
                            System.out.println("Took " + rollCount + " rolls!");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default :
                    System.out.println("Invalid roll!");
                    roll = 0;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Yahtzee!");
            System.out.println("Took " + rollCount + " rolls!");
```